# Open-source Vulnerability Management Tools

Tags: security, open-source

Currently searching for potential industrial cybersecurity vulnerability management open-source tools, I've found *Zeek*, *NetworkMiner*, *Arkime*, *GRASSMARLIN* and *Malcolm* to be potentially part of these.

From now, I'm wondering: am I right with these tools? And do you know other ones addressing such a topic?

Thank you in advance for your help :)